# How to make ConfuserEx "more" secure?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I've been using it for awhile now but noticed that it uses the same constants, such as the module name `koi` for the constants protection.

Is there any way to make this more secure? I've tried downloading the source and changing some things up but either,

1. The obfuscator crashes during obfuscation or...
2. My obfuscated application crashes at startup.

My knowledge of this stuff is extremely limited which is why I'm looking for alternative methods of making it "more" secure.

Comment: It does what it does.  If it is not sufficient, then try another one.  Or write your own.

Comment: The age-old obfuscation adagio: if you think the value of your product is in the source code, then don't distribute the source code - neither in plain text nor in compiled form. Someone dedicated enough will find out what your source does, however much obfuscated. Host your code as a service if you want to prevent that. Your question _"How to make obfuscator X obfuscate in a different way"_ as it is, is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's free for a reason, and what @CodeCaster said.